# a server side mustache.js example using node.js

Tags: node.js, serverside-javascript

I'm looking for an example using `Mustachejs` with `Nodejs`

here is my example but it is not working. `Mustache` is undefined.
I'm using Mustachejs from the master branch.

```
var sys = require('sys');
var m = require("./mustache");

var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function() {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};    
var template = "{{title}} spends {{calc}}";    
var html = Mustache().to_html(template, view);

sys.puts(html);
```

Answer (score 33):

I got your example working by installing mustache via npm, using the correct require syntax and (as Derek said) using mustache as an object not a function

```
npm install mustache
```

then

```
var sys = require('sys');
var mustache = require('mustache');

var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function() {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

var template = "{{title}} spends {{calc}}";

var html = mustache.to_html(template, view);

sys.puts(html);
```

Answer (score 18):

Your example is almost correct.  Mustache is an object, not a function, so it doesn't need the ().  Rewritten as

```
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, view);
```

will make it happier.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Boldr http://boldr.net/create-a-web-app-with-node
Had to add the following  code to mustache.js

```
for (var name in Mustache)
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Mustache, name))
        exports[name] = Mustache[name];
```

Not exactly sure what it is doing but it works.  Will try to understand it now.

Comment: It basically adds everything in the Mustache object to the [special] exports object. This is necessary as this is how modules work in node.js http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/modules.html#modules

Answer (score -2):

Take a look to [A Gentle Introduction to Node.js](http://mrjaba.posterous.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-nodejs)

> To fix I opened up mustache.js and removed the var declaration when Mustache is being created